# Implementing twilio voice outgoing call, what is "Voice Bot"?

Tags: ios, swift, twilio, voip, callkit

I've integrated code from twilio voice quickstart https://github.com/twilio/voice-quickstart-swift and got my app working up to some extent.

I'm facing problem with "Voice Bot". I'm not sure what this is and how I can implement it in different way. This is for outgoing call. After call is completed, Voice Bot is triggered but it doesn't show on the top of my VC where I'm handling all outgoing call related stuff, it remains in the background and making any subsequent call fails. When I go back from VC to other VC then screen flickers and it seems Voice Bot shows sometimes and then flow completes.

I'm not sure what this Voice Bot is and how we can avoid it or redirect to be handled in a VC? All I can guess is that it's from Apple's Call kit if i'm not wrong.

Any help on how to make it work?

Update on comment: I've used cocoapods to install Twilio.
  pod 'TwilioVoice', '~> 2.0'

Here is the code:

```
@IBAction func placeCall(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if (self.call != nil && self.call?.state == .connected) {
        performEndCallAction(uuid: self.call!.uuid)
        self.toggleUIState(isEnabled: false, showCallControl: false)
    } else {
        let uuid = UUID()
        let handle = "Voice Bot" // <==== ????

        performStartCallAction(uuid: uuid, handle: handle)
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you do a cocoapods, carthage, or manual install?

Comment: For general inquiries related to the `Voice SDK` you can file a [support ticket](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/requests/new).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "VC". The Voice Bot is just a hard coded name for the incoming or outgoing caller. For outgoing calls you should set this to a name or identity of the person you are calling. For incoming calls I'd recommend looking up the incoming number in contacts and using the name (or showing the number, if it's not in the contacts). Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

It's the name which appears on callKit. You can change it to be the name of your app or caller name. Apart from this name it has no significance whatsoever. If you are using client-to-client call only then change it to be your app's name. If you are using your app for phone call as well then change it to be caller's name.